# Connect to Windows File Sharing server using VPN

Tags: vpn, smb

I am using VPN to connect to work server. On windows I enter \\Imbserver into explorer address bar and I can see files on server.

When I connect to VPN on mac and try to access imbserver that is found under "shared" in finder i get connection fail and option to "connect as" .. guest doesn't work and I do not have any username or password. - Works without user/pass on windows.

using smb://imbserver is also fail.

How can I access server files on mac??

Answer (score 1):

"connect as" and enter the username and password you use to log into your Windows machine. I expect the reason you don't need a username/pass in Windows is that you're logged into the domain when you log into your machine.

If that doesn't work, try the same approach, but like so:

smb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@imbserver

replacing USERNAME with your username, and PASSWORD with your password

Answer (score 0):

If your user account is a member of a domain (common in office settings), You'll likely need to know your domain AND username..

in the username field when you hit 'connect as', type DOMAIN\USERNAME (but replace those with your actual domain and username)